# Vector size allocation error in R for one dataset but not for different dataset of identical size

Tags: r, memory, random-forest, allocation, party

I have a dataset with two factor variables ("Elicitor1_ID" and "CallerID") and 33 continuous variables. I would like to run two conditional inference random forest models in the R package party: one model to predict "Elicitor1_ID" as a function of the 33 continuous variables, and a separate model to predict "CallerID" as a function of the same 33 predictor variables. Before running each model, I removed all the rows with an NA in the response variable of interest. Since there were more NAs in Elicitor1_ID than CallerID, this resulted in a dataset with 510 rows (elic) for the Elicitor1_ID model, and a dataset with 981 rows (call) for the CallerID model. There were no NAs in any of the predictor variables.

The following code for the Elicitor1_ID model works fine:

```
require(party)
rfelic <- cforest(formula = get("Elicitor1_ID") ~ ., data=elic,
               control=cforest_control(ntree=100, 
                                       mincriterion = qnorm(0.99), maxdepth=5,
                                       fraction=.4, replace=F))
```

But the following code for the CallerID model returns an error message:

```
rfcall <- cforest(formula = get("CallerID") ~ ., data=call,
           control=cforest_control(ntree=100, 
                                   mincriterion = qnorm(0.99), maxdepth=5,
                                   fraction=.4, replace=F))

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.5 Gb
```

I thought this might be because the "call" dataset (981 rows) was larger than the dataset for the "elic" dataset (510 rows), so I tried randomly selecting 510 rows from the "call" dataset and running the model on that. I got the exact same error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.5 Gb
```

Then I thought perhaps the problem was that the response variable "CallerID" has 178 levels compared to only 129 levels for the response variable "Elicitor1_ID". So I randomly selected 129 of the 178 levels in CallerID and created a further subset of the 510-row subsample of call, which only included those 129 levels.

```
require(dplyr)
call1 <- sample_n(call, size=510, replace=F) #randomly sample 510 rows of call
keepIDs <- sample(unique(caller$CallerID), size=129) #randomly select 129 unique caller IDs
call2 <- call[which(call$CallerID %in% keepIDs),]
rfcall2 <- cforest(formula = get("CallerID") ~ ., data=call2,
                  control=cforest_control(ntree=100, 
                                          mincriterion = qnorm(0.99), maxdepth=5,
                                          fraction=.4, replace=F))
```

But I got the same error message again.

I don't understand why R is seemingly having memory issues with the CallerID model but not the Elicitor1_ID model even after I subsampled the CallerID dataset to make it **exactly the same size or smaller than the Elicitor1_ID dataset**. I wish I could include a reproducible example but I'm not sure how to do that since I don't know what aspect of the original data is causing this problem. I would greatly appreciate any advice or thoughts about what might be causing this strange issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the problem is with the number of levels of some of the variables involved. Possibly it's not the response variable directly but one of the (nominal/unordered) splitting variables where searching all possible binary splits becomes too complex. The reason that this occurs only for one but not the other response may be that different variables are selected for splitting in the two cases.

In any case, I wouldn't have high hopes that 178 response levels can be classified well from just 510 observations. So it might be useful to reconsider the general modeling approach first.